# Aside the United States, did any other country challenge Canada's claim of sovereignty in the Arctic?

Tags: international, canada, arctic

> Canada has had historic difficulty supporting its Arctic claims of
> sovereignty due to the sparsity of population, remoteness, and
> difficulty in effectively demonstrating administrative capacity. **Most
> challenges to Canada's arctic sovereignty have historically come from
> the United States.[31] As claims of sovereignty in the Arctic
> solidified with the end of territorial disputes around the Alaska
> panhandles, Canada's efforts at demonstrating sovereignty have shifted
> from the mainland of the north, to the Arctic Archipelago. Most
> recently, Canada's claims that the marine passageways within the
> Archipelago are Canadian internal waters have been actively challenged
> by the United States, who claims instead that these are international
> waters.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctic_policy_of_Canada

The Wikipedia article claim that most challenges to Canada's arctic sovereignty have historically come from from the United States, but it doesn't mention other countries. I would like to know what are some other countries that challenged Canada on that front, and I am especially curious to know if there are any other Western or European countries that did challenge Canada's claim of sovereignty over their arctic territory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are several examples.

- Canada, Russia and Denmark have all made territorial claims on the
  [Lomonosov Ridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lomonosov_Ridge).
- Canada and Denmark have only recently
  [resolved](https://www.dw.com/en/canada-and-denmark-settle-dispute-over-uninhabited-arctic-island/a-62133053) their decades-long dispute over the sovereignty of Hans
  Island/Tartapuluk.